# Codeigniter Routing remove controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I want to route so that the "domain" part dissapears,

```
http://www.domaininfo.za/domain/google.com
```

to something like this

```
http://www.domaininfo.za/google.com
```

I have managed to remove the welcome part but how do i remove domain?

my route file:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
$route['404_override'] = '/';
$route['(:any)'] = "welcome/domain/$1";
```

Comment: and thus they invented **mod-rewrites**

Comment: Don't really understand what you need..You already done it, ain't you?

Comment: I want to remove the "domain" from the url.

Comment: You already did, man..Your routing does that...it takes any 1st segment (which should have been a controller) and reroutes it to whatever you like, so your URL now can be of just one segment

Comment: You must use mod-rewrite then. Routing doesn't eliminate domain from the URL, it just creates an alternate syntax to use...so you could use both still with just the router. Mod-rewrite would literally rewrite any other request to a "no-domain" url before it gets processed by Codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're asking, but does this work for you?

```
$route['(:any)'] = "domain/$1";
```

Comment: no this gives me an error _Unable to load your default controller. Please make sure the controller specified in your Routes.php file is valid._

Comment: @maccen for this to work, you need a controller named "domain" (you can substitute it with whatever controller you want, in any case); other than that, looks perfect for your case

Answer (score 0):

Your routing is dangerous...I would put a regex in the route key to recognize web domains, then route it to welcome/domain/$1. Right now you are routing all values in the controller space to welcome/domain/$1. Mod-rewrite or using regex in your router would be best.